# Set table row height when there are 3 or more rows inside a cell

Tags: html-table, row, cell, multiple-columns

I'm having trouble setting the row height of 3 rows when they are grouped inside 1 cell.
Image illustrates my table:

[image]

Code so far:

```
<table width="600" align="center" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
        <tr>
            <td rowspan="3" width="60%">
            Text text text
            </td>

            <td width="40%" height="100%" valign="baseline">
                <img src="logo.jpg" width="100%">
            </td>   
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td height="10%">
                textfield of 10% height
            </td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td>
                textfield of dynamic height
            </td>
        </tr>
</table>
```

The height of the 3rd row on the right will be dynamic since the height of the column on the left is undetermined. The only fixed heights are the row with the 10% height and the image (though I don't want to set a fixed height for the cell with the image since the image w/h might change anyways).

Comment: So what is it you're trying to do? You mention you're having trouble with the heights and what the fixed heights are, but what specifically do you want these rows to do?

Comment: Achieve what is specified in the image. Right side 1st row = image, 2nd row = 10% height, 3rd row = dynamic height.